# JGit plumbing API - commit new or modified file to non-current branch

Tags: jgit

Sorry, relative novice, but I have not been able to find specific example to address this.   Working on a service that is using Git to store configuration documents.   They would be worked on in branches until "published".
I've been able to do all the querying and fetching of documents from any branch in the local repository where the service would run, without having to "checkout" branch into working directory.   I would like to do the same with a save operation.

I've found examples of using ObjectInserter, TreeFormatter and CommitBuilder to do this, but no explicit/explained example of doing this to specific branch that would produce the same results as switching, adding and committing with porcelain API.

I've played around with RefUpdate after the commit, and think I'm on the right track, but could use some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are trying seems unnecessarily difficult. Why aren't you using JGit's porcelain commands like `CheckoutCommand`, `AddCommand`, `CommitCommand`, etc.?

Comment: I've just got back to implementing this after several weeks.  When I first was playing around I tried with the porcelain JGit, but the return from the CheckoutCommand.call() seemed much slower than the same operation on the command line.  
I was also doing File system writes after the checkout to expected folder, then add, commit.
Is it typical for server side applications to keep changing the local repository working directory?   (Granted this will probably not be a high traffic service)
Thanks

Comment: I would start with the simplest possible solution. That seems to be JGit's command API in this case. Only if performance tests actually show that there is an unacceptable performance impact, you should look for different approaches.